# False Positive in SonarQube Hibernate Transaction

Tags: java, sonarqube

Consider the following code:

```
Transaction tx = null;

try {
  Session currentSession = getCurrentSession();
  tx = currentSession.beginTransaction();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
   if (tx != null) {
     tx.rollback();
   }
}
```

SonarQube with the command-line version of Sonar Scanner (2.5.1) - both the latest versions that I downloaded just the other day, produce the following Blocker Issue:

Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "false"

It occurs on the if (tx != null) check above. But, it is possible that if the call to getCurrentSession() fails, that tx is null...

Comment: Ok. So what's the question!?

Comment: Can you please precise which version of the java analyzer you are using ?

Comment: Jan: read the Title of the post "False Positive..." Why can't tx be null, what if getCurrentSession() fails with a HibernateException? Wouldn't that cause tx to still be null?